# Can I have a virtualbox disk in another disk partition?

Tags: debian, arch-linux, partition, virtualbox

I once tried to install arch linux in my USB stick a while ago, and accidentally wiped my windows [by converting it into lvm2 like that...] [BTW, i was happy though cause, there was nothing precious in that damn windows]

Now my question is can I have virtualbox hard disk be in those other partitions, like this is my hard disk partition

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 315.8G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  46.2G  0 part /
└─sda6   8:6    0   3.8G  0 part [SWAP]
```

The sda1 is my windows drive and sda2 is also just crap cause there is nothing precious in it, my linux drive is sda5, [i use debian, btw],

Now my question is can I configure virtualbox in a way, that it just stores my all virtualbox hard disk in sda1, or sda2?

Down I provide more information...

```
   sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x31f26811

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 209727487 209725440   100G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       209727488 871909375 662181888 315.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       871909416 976769023 104859608    50G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       871909418 968710185  96800768  46.2G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       968714240 976769023   8054784   3.8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 5 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

This is my os information:

```
uname -a
Linux doraemon 5.10.0-10-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.84-1 (2021-12-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

[Sorry if I couldn't explain my problem clearly, but if you need more information, then I am ready to do that also]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move all vhd files manually and reattach them.

> Now my question is can I configure virtualbox in a way, that it just stores my all virtualbox hard disk in sda1, or sda2?

No, unless your join these two partitions using LVM, and then you may mount this new partition to `/home/user/VirtualBox VMs`. You'll need to move it out of the way first.

If I misunderstood you and you need to use physical partitions as is in your VMs, this is possible but not recommended.

You can find a description in the manual under
[Advanced topics / Advanced storage configuration / Using a raw host hard disk from a guest](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk)

Comment: kk, thanks for your advice, but if in the future, I want to create a new virtual hard disk can I just write the path of the hard disk like /media/usb/.../ [by mounting], further questions, will this have an impact on the systmem or is it not recommended, if yes then why?, Now my main focus question is Can I just create a new virtual hard disk in virtualbox, in the future if needed?

Comment: When creating a new VM you can just specify its path as the first step in the wizard.

Comment: Kk, will try and see if that works perfectly or not....